# How to split single didgit on periods with apply two or more modifying coefficients?

Tags: math, statistics, coefficients, trend

For example I know that we sold **5000** pieces of something in **previous month**.
I know that month split into weeks and every month we **sell on 20% more than in previous month**. This is some kind of **global trend** that goes for years.

So I can know exact amount of sales every week by using this scheme:
Month split into 4 weeks and we sold 5000 things in that month. First week we selling 100%, second is 105, third is 110 and last one is 115.

We can use this as coefficients:

```
1 week    2 week    3 week    4 week /*Total 5000 things*/
100       105       110       115    /*we can summ coeffs and get 430*/
0.2325    0.2441    0.2558    0.2674 /*we divide 100/430, 105/430 and etc to normalize it*/
1162.5    1220.5    1279      1337   /*we multiply 0.2325 on 5000 to get sales amount in first week and etc*/
```

And that's really working, each of these values 1162.5, 1220.5, 1279, 1337 greater than previous on 5%.

But that's where things gets unclear. We also know that there is seasonal changes. We know that fist week we sell a little bit less, than in second, in second a little more, then third, and third is way bigger, than last. We can describe that seasonal changes as another set of coefficients:

```
1 week    2 week    3 week    4 week /*Total 5000 things*/
0.9       1         0.9       0.5    /*summ is 3.3*/
0.2727    0.3030    0.2727    0.1515 /*normalized*/
1363.5    1515      1363.5    757.5  /*real sales per week*/
```

So we calculated separately each week sales like if we had **global trend only** and **seasonal changes only**, but how we can **mix** those?

I don't know what to do with 1337 and 757.5 for last week and etc.

Comment: If second table are week/week ratio, then you cannot mix global coefficients with these ratios. Yet another note: in the first case week coefficient is about 4.6635% (1.2 in the power 1/4)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about statistics / mathematics / economics / finance instead of directly about programming or software development.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematics question and not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your second table is really direct week/week ratio and it is the same in different months as it looks from your second example, then I don't understand where your trouble is. What's wrong with simple

```
amount(month_index, week_index) = 5000 * ((1.2) ^ month_index) * normalized_week_coefffcient[week_index]
```

In other words first use your 20% per month to calculate total amount in the month and then split that total amount between weeks according to normalized week coefficients from your Table #2

Comment: The problem that I made bad example by over thinking how to describe what I need. What to do if every week in month uses table #2, but December's last week in year always have secondary coefficients to apply (ppls buy more for New Year), like **1    1    1   3**? So first we need to apply table #2 and then mix it with that new coefficients.

Comment: @Kosmos, I'm not sure I understnad your New-Year issue. I expect that New-Year period is special enough that usual 20% per month growth also doesn't apply both for it and for next January (it is probably even less than December). So I think it makes sense to create a separate logic for whole December (or wherever your buying spree starts)